# How to get controller input when using the SteamVR Interaction System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steam, virtual-reality

I want to just simply get controller input from the user in my VR game, and i also want to use the SteamVR interaction system so that I can have easy UI stuff be implemented. However, I cannot get input from the controller off of the Hand script.

All that I did was drag in the "Player" prefab, and then write a script to go on the Hand object to get input from the triggers.

```
    private Hand _hand;                     // The hand object
    private SteamVR_Controller.Device controller; // the controller property of the hand


    void Start ()
    {
        // Get the hand componenet
        _hand = GetComponent<Hand>();
        // Set the controller reference
        controller = _hand.controller;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
            // === NULL REFERENCE === //
        if ( controller.GetHairTrigger())
        {
            Debug.Log ("Trigger");
        }

    }
```

This gives me a null ref exception to the "controller" object. I have also tried getting the controller component in `OnEnable()` and `Awake()` and that didn't work either. Even in `Update()`. So for some reason the `Hand` class of SteamVR does not hold a reference to the controller. Am I doing something wrong?Am I missing some sort of index specification when i get the controller?

I am able to get controller input like this:

```
   private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;       // The tracked object that is the controller

    private SteamVR_Controller.Device Controller    // The device property that is the controller, so that we can tell what index we are on
    {
        get { return SteamVR_Controller.Input((int)trackedObj.index); }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Get the tracked object componenet
        trackedObj = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
    }

    void Update()
 {
     if(Controller.GetHairTrigger()){
          Debug.Log("hey trigger");
     }
  }
```

But then I cannot use the Interaction system. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2):

I would really suggest you to add Valve's free [HTC.UnityPlugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64219) on top of SteamVR integration,
thus you can quickly access the controllers input with

```
using UnityEngine;
using HTC.UnityPlugin.Vive;
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        // get trigger
        if (ViveInput.GetPressDown(HandRole.RightHand, ControllerButton.Trigger))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without installing any additional dependencies other than SteamVR, attach the script to one of the `Hand` components. It's a child of the `Player` prefab in the SteamVR asset folder.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grab: MonoBehaviour {
    private Valve.VR.InteractionSystem.Hand hand;

    void Start () {
        hand = gameObject.GetComponent<Valve.VR.InteractionSystem.Hand>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (hand.controller == null) return;

        // Change the ButtonMask to access other inputs
        if (hand.controller.GetPressDown(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("Trigger down")
        }

        if (hand.controller.GetPress(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("Trigger still down")
        }

        if (hand.controller.GetPressUp(SteamVR_Controller.ButtonMask.Trigger))
        {
            Debug.Log("Trigger released")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This no longer works in current Steam plugin for Unity - there is no controller property within hand.
Can anyone suggest the proper way currently? I am having a hard time reading the controller inputs with the new system.

Comment: I am using this way: Firs: using Valve.VR.InteractionSystem;  then you can access to hands like so: void Update()
        {
            foreach (var hand in Player.instance.hands)
            {... I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to you can work with hands:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Valve.VR.InteractionSystem;

    public class ShowControllers : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool showController = false;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
        {
            foreach (var hand in Player.instance.hands)
            {
                if (showController)
                {
                    hand.ShowController();
                    hand.SetSkeletonRangeOfMotion(Valve.VR.EVRSkeletalMotionRange.WithController);
                }
                else
                {
                    hand.HideController();
                hand.SetSkeletonRangeOfMotion(Valve.VR.EVRSkeletalMotionRange.WithoutController);
            }
            }
        }
    }
```